# How to show more than 100 tasks //TODOs at once in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, todo

As the title says, how do I display more than 100 tasks at once in Tasks window in Eclipse? Alternatively, how do I browse tasks past 100?

I have a lot of .c files in my project with many //TODOs

When I go to Tasks window, it shows:

> Filter matched 100 of 158 items

I can't find a *sane* way to go past item 100... that is, I don't see a button, or right click option saying go to next 100 items..

The *insane* way I use currently, is to sort by different columns, ie resource, path, location, ascending AND descending.. then copy paste to outside app and cut out duplicates.. this doesn't guarantee I get every task if I have more than 200 tasks.

There has to be a better way!

This is running Standard Eclipse 3.5 CDT installation on Ubuntu 9.04., but had this problem on 3.4 and 3.3, as well.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! Can't believe I missed the little arrow..

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The little arrow at the top-right side of the Taks view display a menu with the 'Preferences' item.

In the 'Preferences' dialog , you can define:

```
Limit visible items per group to:
```

And enter a value greater than 100.
Here is an illustration, with the mandatory hand-made circle (quite ugly in this case):

[image: limit markers]

---

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800191/6309) [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33431391/6309), for Eclipse 4+, this has changed.
4.5 (mars) and 4.6 (Neon) actually have a "`Use item limit`" field.

[image: settings]

Comment: Starting in Eclipse version 4.2.2 This UI has changed.  See my answer below for the current information.

Answer (score 7):

In Eclipse Version: 4.2.2 There is no preferences or properties.  You must click the arrow and go to **"Configure Contents"** Then change the field that says **"Number of items visible per group: "** in the bottom right side of the dialog box.

Answer (score 4):

In the title bar of the tasks view, there is a downward arrow (right to the left of the closing X). It opens a dropdown menu that has a "Properties" entry, which allows you to specify how many tasks to show.

Answer (score 3):

Click the **View** menu in the **Tasks** window (the little downwards-pointing triangle) and click **Preferences**. There's a **"Limit visible items per group to:"** field that has a default value of 100.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse Neon , it is changed to

Title bar of tasks view->Downward arrow -> Configure Contents -> Use Item Limits

It is set to 100 by default, either change it to any number you want ,  or uncheck the Use Item Limits box, to see all the issues/tasks .

caveat: It has to done for every window , as I am not sure how to do it globally.